# space character in url is coming up as '%20'

Tags: uri

one of my clients website (built on D7) has the '%20' sign coming up in url as a result of a space. My only way around till now has been to use'-' instead of a space between the product names. But i cannot have a '-' between every products name. Please advise

- A 'non html/non - technical / not sure what plugins we have already installed' person

:|

Comment: use pathauto module

Answer (score 4):

%20 is a standard replacement for the space character in URLs.

If you're using pathauto for clean urls ( presumably ), it should remove those from the URL, and replace with hyphens.

/admin/config/search/path/settings

> SEPARATOR
>
> Character used to separate words in titles. This will replace any
>   spaces and punctuation characters. Using a space or + character can
>   cause unexpected results.

Check that a hyphen "-" character is being used there.

The regular product title can have spaces, but pathauto should replace those with the separator character in the URL.